# How can i call send and accept Json object from angular to backend on play frmaework?

Tags: json, angularjs, scala, playframework-2.0

I have written a front end in angularjs and back end in scala on play frmaework. Now i want to send json object from angular to back end by calling a method which returns json object also. I have written the following code in angularjs, scala and on route file`

```
angular.js

$scope.show=function(){
        var url="localhost:9000"
        var urlText=
        {
            "url":$scope.url
        };
        $http({
            method:"GET",
            url:url+"/getUrl",
            params:{
                data:urlText
            }
        })
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.url-title.push(data.title)
                $scope.url-description.push(data.description)
                $scope.url-img.push(data.img)
            })

    }


Controllers.scala

object Application extends Controller{
def returnUrl(text:JsValue):JsValue ={
    val str=(text \ "url").as[String]
    val obj=new UrlPreview()
    obj.returnDescription(str)
    val jsonObj:JsValue=Json.obj(
      "title" ->obj.returnTitle(),
      "description"->obj.returnDescription(),
      "img"->obj.returnImage()
    )

    return jsonObj

  }
}

Routes

GET         /getUrl/{text}                    controllers.Application.returnUrl
```

` I am new in web development.So i dont have enough idea. If you have any idea or where I am doing mistake. Please share some ideas

Comment: Please post any errors you're getting, and a more specific question. Have you checked out https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson? Specifically the bit on creating a complex Scala object using Json.toJson and a Map?

Comment: @jspacek not enough arguments for method returnUrl: (text: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)play.api.libs.json.JsValue. Unspecified value parameter text.  This one is the error

Comment: it sounds like you're not passing the correct params to the returnUrl, and I see your last line just has {text}. Do you have a stack trace from your play ui on localhost:9000? That would give more info.

Comment: I have the following line in route file    GET         /getUrl/:text                    controllers.Application.returnUrl(text:JsValue)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send json you should POST or PUT instead of GET on the angular side. In the play side then the body parser comes into play, so that the route does not contain any parameter and in the action method you can use e.g. request.body.json.